Locus of centre of circle which bisects two smaller circles
Consider two fixed non-intersecting circles  ( not necessarily of equal radii ). A circle which intersects both the circles also bisects their circumference. What is the locus of the centre of this circle ?
I drew a rough diagram as follows where the smaller circles are fixed :

I know that the common chord of variable circle and any fixed circle is the radical axis which I don't think is a useful information. But my teacher said that the centre of variable circle lies on the radical axis of the fixed circles , which I do not think is correct and also I can't prove it. How can I approach to find the locus ? Any hints are appreciated.
This problem was given to me after introducing radical axis. So I was trying to solve it by that method.

The chord between the intersection points of each circle is a diameter with midpoint the centre of each circle. The perpendiculars through these centres meet at $(h,k)$.

@YNK I did not said that non-intersecting circles have common chord. I said that the variable circle has a common chord with any of the fixed smaller circles. Also , that common chord is radical axis of those circles.

@Paul Thanks sir. But how to proceed with this info ? It's not looking trivial to find the point of intersection of the normals.

Let us explicitly state a result that is equivalent to the claimed property, having explicit notations, and making sentences that come with explicit geometric relations instead of "bisecting a circumference".


We start with two $\color{blue}{blue}$ circles with centers in $O,O'$, and radii respectively $R,R'$. Consider the pink side bisector of $OO'$, and reflect the two circles with respect to it, so that two $\color{brown}{brown}$ circles appear, the one centered in $O$ has radius $R'$, the one centered in $O'$ has radius $R$.
Let $X$ be a point in the same plane of the circles, we draw the rays $XO$, $XO'$, which intersect the two $\color{brown}{brown}$ circles in $S,T$, and respectively $S',T'$. We draw perpendiculars on $XO$, respectively $XO'$ in $O$, respectively $O'$, and the intersection points with the two $\color{blue}{blue}$ circles are denoted by $A,B$, respectively $A',B'$. (So $AB$, $A'B'$ are diameters of the two $\color{blue}{blue}$ circles.)
Then:

If $X$ is on the radical axis of the $\color{brown}{brown}$ circles $\odot(O, R')$ and $\odot(O', R)$, then $XA=XB=XA'=XB'$, so the four points $A,B;A',B'$ are on the same circle centered in $X$, which "bisects" each of the two blue circumferences.
If  the four points $A,B;A',B'$ are on the same circle centered in $X$, i.e. $XA=XB=XA'=XB'$, then $X$ is on the radical axis of the $\color{brown}{brown}$ circles $\odot(O, R')$ and $\odot(O', R)$.


This was the hard work. For the proof we note that $XA=XB$, and $XA'=XB'$, and then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
XA^2 - XA'{}^2
&=(XO^2+R^2)-(XO'{}^2+R'{}^2)
\\
&=(XO^2-R'{}^2)-(XO'{}^2-R^2)
\\
&=(XO-R')(XO+R')-(XO'-R)(XO'+R)
\\
&=XS\cdot XT-XS'\cdot XT'
\\
&=
\operatorname{Power}(X, \ \odot(O,R')) -
\operatorname{Power}(X, \ \odot(O',R))
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So $XA=XA'$ is equivalent to $X$ having the same power w.r.t. the two brown circles.
$\square$

" If X is on the radical axis of the brown
circles $⊙(O,R′)$
and $⊙(O′,R)$
, then $XA=XB=XA′=XB′$" Can you please elaborate it why ? Thanks !

I have only been introduced radical axis and power of a point first time in a coordinate geometry :(

The problem gives us two circles, the blue ones. Then the problem wants us to find some "complicated locus" for a property $P$. It turns out that it is a line. Moreover, it is a specific line, the radical axis of two other circles, the brown ones, easily constructed from the initial blue ones. There is a definition and a construction of the radical axis of two circles, so everything makes sense. Let $a$ be this axis. Now i want to prove something, so a lot of letters come into play. The letter that denotes the point with the locus is $X$. In order to show that $a$ is the wanted locus, two...

...two things are needed: (i) Show that if a point $X$ is on $a$, then it has the wanted property $P$, which is $XA=XA'$, and (ii) Show that if a point $X$ has the wanted property $P$, which is $XA=XA'$, then $X$ is on the axis $a$. The proof gives a relation between two quantities, the difference of the squares of $XA$, $XA'$, and the difference of the powers of the point $X$ w.r.t. the brown circles. So if $X$ is on $a$, by definition of the radical axis of two circles the two powers of the point are equal, their difference is zero, the difference of the squares of $XA,XA'$ is zero, so...

... so building the circle centered in $X$ with radius $XA=XA'$ will cut the circumferences of the initial blue circles in two equal pieces each, the cut points being $A,B$ for the first blue circle, $A',B'$ for the second one. This is one direction. The other direction is reading the above backwards. (Start with a circle centered in $X$ that cuts the blue circles each in two arcs of equal lengths, introduce $A,B;A',B'$, the cut points, observe that $XA=XA'$, ... (follows the chain of thoughts in reverse direction), so the power of $X$ w.r.t. the brown circles is the same, so $X\in a$.
